# ESD protection during lightning storms

Tags: safety, esd, lightning, equipment

I'm new to electronics, and I'm currently building my electronics area. Let's say that I have an ESD bench mount drilled into my wooden workbench, and this ESD bench mount is then connected to the "ring" of the power outlet. Prior to attaching anything to the power outlet, I used one of those power outlet voltage testers, which indicated that it was functioning correctly. I then have my wrist strap connected to the ESD bench mount.

Now let's say that there is a lightning storm. In such a situation, are there any additional risks to human or electronics safety? Is there anything that I need to be mindful of in such a situation? Should I behave differently in such a situation?

Comment: Don't directly connect yourself to the mains power supply. Sometimes the earth will become live, either due to a lightning strike or, more commonly, a mains fault. Use a dissipative technique: [6 steps to choosing and installing an ESD working surface](https://www.rs-online.com/designspark/6-steps-to-choosing-and-installing-an-esd-working-surface) Just because the power outlet is functioning correctly now is no guarantee it will function correctly in future.

Comment: @tim Thanks for the link. I'm using an ESD earth plug https://www.oritech.com.au/clipsal-esd-earth-plug.html . So the ESD bench mount is attached to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any electronics or metal surfaces can be an increased risk during a thunderstorm. A direct hit near your house can induce large currents and voltages in many unexpected locations and injuries are rare but they are possible.

ESD wrist straps are the least of your worries.  All ESD wrist straps have (or should have) a ~1 M resistor in them.  The resistor doesn't have a high enough voltage rating to withstand something like a direct lightning hit, but it will limit current from lower voltage sources such as line voltage or an induced EMF from a nearby lightning strike to a safe value.

On the other hand, most electronics with 3 pin power plugs such as desktop computers, appliances and any test and measurement equipment you have will have exposed metal connected directly to the grounded conductor from the power outlet with no current limiting resistor.  In the unlikely event that your ground becomes dangerous those sources are a much bigger concern than your wrist strap.

Do not do what another poster has suggested and bring in an external ground or using a copper pipe or plumbing fixture as your source of ground unless you also connect it to your wiring ground.  The reason for this is that your wiring ground is already exposed in a lot of places.  If you bring a different ground and they are for some reason at a different potential (such as a nearby lightning strike) now you have a large potential difference and capacity to receive a shock.  At least in the US, copper plumbing and metal  building components such as support beams should already be connected to the wiring ground exactly to prevent these sorts of differences from arising.  Unfortunately this is not terribly reliable.  A common case is that a pipe leaks and a short section is replaced with PVC since it is cheaper and easier to install.  This can create islands of ungrounded pipes.  It is rarely a problem, but you don't want to accidentally rely on such a section to ground your workbench.

Answer (score -1):

There is more my experience rather than books.

Depending the building age, location, you cannot really never trust the earth on the sockets. I had the case where the ground somehow was a few V above earth. Whilst this should not happen, you never know, especially if the building is old.

I also had the case where I had about 100V difference between two neutral of two different sockets a few meters apart which was causing me all sorts of problems until I found that out.

Old buildings sometimes even don't have true earth and the neutral is connected together with the earth, this was to save cost (running 2 wires instead of 3) which is relatively dangerous, especially if the neutral is cut downstream, the earth line can become energized, which has caused many accidents. We had to rewire my entire house because of that.

You can also have someone that has wrongly wired a plug or a defective device, shorting the earth and phase when connected, in which case the earth can become energized a few ms before the breaker activates, which would be enough to burn any circuit you are working on if your circuit is grounded somewhere else (like through an oscilloscope connected to another plug on another circuit).

When grounding the workbench, I usually try to find some metallic structure connected to the ground, like radiator/water pipes, structural beams, and if there isn't any, I take a  metal stick, stick it to the ground (like on the grass outside the building) and pull a wire from it through a window and if that isn't possible drill something in the concrete floor.

I certainly don't trust the earth on a socket in my area (and probably anywhere) and wouldn't plug it to my wrist. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I live in a small apartment building, so I don't have that luxury. Does using the voltage tester not tell us whether the socket is working correctly in the way that you describe? I know that the voltage tester doesn't check everything, so I'm not sure. What if I use a multimeter to manually check the socket? I don't have any other option for a workspace, so I need to do whatever I can to ensure that this setup is safe, and then take the risk (which I think is relatively low, given what you have described, no?).

Comment: See here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-GVxM9O6jA

Comment: You can test the voltage, but it won't tell you whether there is a wiring issue as some fault can happen as described in my post. if you have metal water pipes that can be an option.

Comment: ESD wrist straps have resistors built into them to limit the flow of current in case they touch a live circuit.  On the other hand every other metal device in your house has the exposed metal connected to the ground wire.  If your ground is miswired, everything in your house *except* the ESD wrist strap becomes dangerous.